# Block Reward vs. Transaction fee in blockchain

Tags: blockchain

1. Can Somebody Explain Block Reward vs. Transaction fee?
2. these are separate benefits that miners receive?
3. How does it work?

Answer (score 3):

Each block that gets accepted to the main chain results in generation of new coins, or in other words a Block Reward to the miner to compensate them for the effort they have put in mining the block. Currently this stands at 12.5 coins for every accepted block, and this reward halves after approximately every 210,000 accepted blocks. Check [this](https://www.bitcoinblockhalf.com/)  and [this](https://www.anythingcrypto.com/guides/bitcoin-mining-block-rewards-2018) for more info.

On the other hand transaction fees is something that a user pays from their own wallets to a miner, so that their transaction is accepted faster for processing. Check [this](https://bitcoinfees.info/) for more info.

Comment: Funny, because I just googled this page :) stackoverflow isn't just for people who ask, it's for the whole community